# Docker with Debian Wheezy is lacking lot of commands!

Tags: debian, docker, netcat

I have created a docker image from debian:wheezy, to follow a tutorial. I am just wondering how useful is this image because it does not support many commands. For example:

"nc", but also (and the list can be long), vi, ps, apt, wget, dpkg ...

I am just finding a way to install the netcat tool and finally run this script in the container:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "Logging Mailer has started.\n"
while true
do
   MESSAGE=$(nc -l -p 33333)
   printf "[Message]: %s\n" "$MESSAGE" > $1
   sleep 1
done
```

Of course this does not work. Any idea how i can extend the image to support more commands? Thanks and I hope it is not off topic here.

Comment: Is using a container really the best for your use case? Also wheezy has reached EOL over a year ago. If you do go with containerization, please use a supported version of Debian.

Comment: Find _Stretch_ here: https://www.debian.org/releases/

Comment: It sounds like you don't really understand how docker works.

Comment: thanks for your comments I am indeed using Debian:Jessie and things are much better now. @wurtel maybe a more constructive feedback would be better, infact the issue was not related to Docker but to the image.

Comment: basically with docker you take a base install, and if you need `nc`, you use a build script to install `nc` in that base install which leaves you with a new image that is the base install + nc. That is docker 101.

Comment: @wurtel correct but there are tools which are present in base image. Wheezy looked very poor in this sense (not only for netcat). Jessie is much richer in term of tools... However I learned now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re running into two issues:

- the point of a good container base image is to provide a minimal but viable base on which to build whatever you need for your application;
- the Wheezy image contains, unsurprisingly, Wheezy-era packages.

You *will* find the essentials needed to install other packages, so `dpkg` and `apt-get` are present. The `apt` command didn’t exist in Wheezy, so it’s not available. When Wheezy was still relevant, you could install additional packages by running `apt-get update` (because the image ships with no indexes, to reduce its size) and then `apt-get install ...`. This won’t work any more though because the Wheezy package repositories are no longer available from the locations referenced in `/etc/apt/sources.list` inside the image.

I won’t explain how to fix the Wheezy image, because you shouldn’t be using it for anything new. You should use `debian:stretch` nowadays.

Comment: thanks indeed I switched to Jessie and is fine. Sorry for the basic question. That was a tutorial, maybe too old :)

Comment: For sake of completeness I want to remark that the issue with Wheezy that not even dpkg, apt-get were present so I could not start any installation at all.

Comment: @toto' I’m not sure how you managed that, I ran `docker run -it debian:wheezy` before writing my answer and the image most definitely does have `dpkg` and `apt-get`.

Comment: I have used a Dockerfile with something like:                                                 
FROM debian:wheezy
RUN groupadd -r -g 2200 example && \
      useradd -rM -g example -u 2200 example
ENV APPROOT="/app" \
APP="mailer.sh" \
VERSION="0.6"
LABEL base.name="Mailer Archetype" \
      base.version="${VERSION}"
WORKDIR $APPROOT
ADD . $APPROOT
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/mailer.sh"]
EXPOSE 33333                                                                                                 
Then I attached a container with shell to it and I tried those commands that were not-found.

Comment: How did you go about attaching your container with shell? Your commands probably failed because they weren’t available in *that* container, not the Wheezy-based one.

Comment: like this docker exec -it logging-mailer /bin/bash

Comment: Ok I retried all once again and strange (now is different!) now i can see that apt-get present.